# Is it feasible to build a bomb big enough to destroy Pluto?

Tags: planets, weapons

Assuming that:

- Cost is no concern
- The bomb hits the planet
- The only effect involved is the explosion of the bomb.

Can a bomb be big enough to destroy Pluto?
The bomb Must Destroy half of the planet at least

Comment: Define "destroy." What form do you want the remnants of Pluto to be? A bunch of asteroids? How big? Fully vaporized? 50% of its outer bulk flung into orbit? What are you looking for here? What level of technology is allowed? Modern tech? Near future plausible? Sci-fi level?

Comment: You might like [this exploration of geocide methods](https://qntm.org/destroy). Earth is a bit bigger than Pluto, of course, so some of them may even be feasible.

Comment: Which planet does the bomb hit? Is pluto expected to be destroyed by that planets shrapnel?

Comment: Is this today's technology, political and social refrence?  There are many obstacles for each.

Comment: I just want to add to Joe KIssling's post (good one, by the way): Another way you could do it is somehow reflect the sun's/a star's energy and beaming ("fired" through reflecting) the planet's core.

Comment: But... Why Pluto?

Answer (score 23):

**Yes**

The answer is [here](https://astroengine.com/2009/10/30/what-will-it-take-to-blow-up-pluto/). Only takes 25 Billion nukes the size of the [Tzar Bomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba) to do it.

**The process**

To completely destroy a planet you need to impart more energy into it than its gravitational binding energy which is calculated using the following equation

$E = \frac{3GM^2}{5R}$

Filling in the universal gravitational constant, Mass and Radius of pluto; $6.67\times10^{-11} m^3kg^{-1}s^{-2}$, $1.3\times10^{22}kg$, $1.15\times10^6m$ respectivly. You get $5.9\times10^{27}$ joules of energy.

Which is ~25 billion times the energy in the Tzar Bomba 
with only $2.4\times10^{17}$ joules.

Comment: you beated me on the second for posting the answer...

Comment: Super Nuke!! just use 50 billion rolls of duck tape and tape them together.

Comment: can you anyway detail a bit more the answer? As it is now it is "link only"

Comment: @L.Dutch Haha my apologies. Sure thing, I'll expand

Comment: Feasible...  you keep using this word.  I do not think it means what you think it means =)

Comment: Joe said, "To completely destroy a planet"... but Pluto isn't a planet! Do those calculations still hold? </joking>

Comment: @SRM I can't claim to have destroyed any significant celestial bodies so we can't be sure. This warrants experimentation, let's destroy mercury and pluto to find out.

Comment: What's the mass of the resulting super bomb in relation to Pluto?

Comment: @sphennings $5.192\times10^{-6}$ % of plutos mass

Comment: The equation you use is for a *uniform* sphere, and I'm not sure this is a good measure of the energy to "destroy a planet." The gravitational binding energy is equal to the gravitational potential energy in the system, but "destruction" doesn't require breaking the entire rock down into individual particles. This also ignores effects like what component of energy would just become kinetic energy in the planet's orbit, be lost in internal potential energy (e.g., chemical reactions or phase changes), etc. This makes a decent theoretical start, but the practicalities might be very different.

Comment: @SRM: Yes it is, the silliness of certain astronomical bodies aside.  See the New Horizons info.  It's got everything a planet needs: moons (more than Earth has!), mountains, seas (even if they're frozen nitrogen), and apparently lots of interesting geology (if that's the right word) going on.

Comment: @jpmc26 It get's us within an order of magnitude, it's plenty good enough. At this scale, the only significant obstacle is the gravity binding the planet together, so delivering energy equal to that to the planet should make pluto not pluto anymore.

Comment: @JoeKissling Still not convinced that sitting a bunch of nukes on the surface achieves the desired end result, which is admittedly unspecified. And an order of magnitude is a pretty big deal here.

Comment: @jpmc26 you wouldn't detonate at the surface, you detonate at the core.

Comment: @JoeKissling "[Your wife's gonna be opening your ketchup bottles the rest of your life.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120591/quotes?item=qt0459179)"

Comment: Considering the average temperature of Pluto (-218 degrees Celsius ) and the heat produced by thermonuclear devices, have you factored in the vaporization aspect of said weapon(s)?

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya this is the energy to blow the planet apart, not vaporize it

Comment: Perhaps you took my meaning wrong. Your introducing a considerable amount of thermal change as well ans your "blow it apart" energy.  This thermal change will alter they dynamics of the object being "blown apart"

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya yes, there will be some heating but given the sheer magnitude of what we are dealing with, comparatively speaking, the heating will be minimal. Apparently we only needed to destroy half the planet anyway.

Answer (score 3):

**No**

It would take 25 billion nukes, each the size of the largest bomb ever tested on Earth to be simultaneously detonated. This is not feasible with modern technology, or any reasonable projection of future technology.

For example, There are about 5.5 million tonnes of extractable uranium on Earth. If all this were converted to fissionable plutonium (impossible but as an upper limit) and used as a nuclear trigger in a thermonuclear weapon you would need at least 10kg of plutonium per bomb (optimistic). That means there is not enough radioactive matter on Earth to make more than 500 million bombs. And practically you can't just convert Uranium to Plutonium. Tsar bomba probably used a lot more Plutonium (For some reason the detailed technical specification aren't available online). However you analyse it you end up way short of the required amount of energy.

No explosive device made with conceivable tech can destroy even the smallest (dwarf) planet.

Comment: What do you mean when you say conceivable tech?

Comment: I mean without magic.

Comment: then I will disagree with your last statement. It takes no magic to construct 25 billion tsar bombs, I grant you that there is likely not enough fissile material to build enough, but it could be done. Additionally, a sufficient quantity of antimatter could supply the explosive force necessary wipe the planet out too. Current production is very low, but it's not inconceivable that we could get better at making it.

Comment: If fissionable matter (uranium plutonium) is the limiting factor (I'm not sure that it is) then you build a smaller number of fusion bombs with a larger amount of deuterium and tritium.  A fusion bomb uses a fission bomb to start its reaction bat there after it uses fissionable material (isotopes of hydrogen) and earth has a lot of hydrogen.       All that said it is still not feasible just a few orders of magnitude closer to feasible.

Comment: I'm sticking with my answer. It is not feasible to build a bomb big enough to destroy Pluto. It is not feasible using any conceivable technology. We are not just a few orders of magnitude short. Just fiddling around with adding more tritium, or even using antimatter, isn't going to change my conclusion: We just can't do this. Even dwarf planets are too big to blow up with a bomb. The maths in Joe's answer is completely correct, but his conclusion is entirely wrong (unless his answer is ironic)

Comment: @JamesK By all means stick to your answer, but I will say I disagree with your statement that it could not be done. A sufficient quantity of antimatter will certainly do the trick.